Book Recommendations for Exercises and Problems in Linear Algebra
I’m preparing an undergraduate-level exam for linear algebra. I’ve heard that the exam questions are not fully abstract but are somewhere between abstract and applied (engineering-related) problems.
Therefore, I’m searching for a suitable textbook that
(1) includes enough exercises and somewhat challenging problems, and
(2) covers an extensive range of topics, such as the Jordan canonical form.
Below is the list of textbooks I'm considering:
Introduction To Linear Algebra 6/E by Gilbert Strang
Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon
Exercises and Problems in Linear Algebra by JM Erdman
The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know by Jonathan S. Golan

You could have a look at these older posts: Any good Graduate Level linear algebra textbook for practice/problem solving? and Where are the resources for a collection of linear algebra problems? (Actually, some of the books listed in your question are mentioned there.)
